# MariaDb one instance vs. many having hundreds of databases on Ubuntu server

Tags: database, mariadb

I'm finishing a web app that consumes a lot of data. Currently there are 150 tables per db, many tables with 1,000 or less records, some with 10,000 or less records and just a few with 100,000 or less records and having a database per customer. I'm setting up a server with 64GB RAM, 1 TB SSD NVMe, Xeon 4 cores at 4GHz and 1GB bandwidth. I'm planning to make 10 instances of MariaDb with 6GB RAM each and the rest for the OS (Ubuntu 18 64-bit) putting 10-15 databases per instance.

Do you think this could be a good approach for the project?

Comment: If all you are concerned about just now is performance, I would advise to start with 1 DB. Simple is beautiful. Since this is a new app, you really do not know how it is going to behave & what the real needs will be. Also, remember you will need to replicate & keep in synch all your master data which is not as easy as it sounds. Also, is there a logical way to divide data between DBs? Will you need aggregated reports across DBs?Will you interface data from other systems? If so, how do you decide which Db to update when? This is just the tip of the iceberg. Thus start small & grow with your app

Comment: camba1, thanks for replying. My huge mistake not saying this : this is the new web version of some desktop app, right now there are 100+ customers using the app, thats why exists that amount of info on those DBs, Table's indexes maybe are not perfect but they've been working very nice and smooth these years. My real concern is not creating a big big bottleneck in server by putting all of them together, thats why I think several instances might help.

Answer (score 0):

Although 15000 tables is a lot, I see no advantage in setting up multiple instances on a single machine.  Here's the rationale:

- Unless you have lousy indexes, even a single instance will not chew up all the CPUs.
- Having 10 instance means the ancillary data (tables, caches, other overhead) will be repeated 10 times.
- When one instance is busy, it cannot rob RAM from the other instances.
- If you do a table scan on 100K rows in a 6G instance (perhaps 4G for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`), it may push the other users in that instance out of the buffer_pool.  Yeah, there are DBA things you could do, but remember, you're not a DBA.

150 tables?  Could it be that there is some "over-normalization"?

Comment: Rick, thanks for replying. There are a lot of catalogs : customers, items, providers etc, and several types of operations : sales, purchases, returns, etc. each and every tables is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually a bit surprised that you are worried about 150 tables where the max size of some tables is 100k or fewer rows?

That certainly does not look like much of a problem for modern hardware that you are planning to use. I will, however, suggest allocating more RAM and use a large enough InnoDB bufferpool size, 70%, of your total ram is the suggested number by MariaDB.

I have seen clients running MariaDB with much larger data sets and a lot more tables + very high concurrency!

Anyways, the best way to proceed is, of course, to test during your UAT cycles with the similar to production data loads. I am still sure it's not going to be a problem.

If you can provide a Master/Slave setup and use MariaDB MaxScale on top, while MaxScale can provide you with automatic db server, connection, failover & transaction replay which gives you the highest level of availability, it also takes care of load balancing with its cool "Read/Write" splitting service. Your servers load will be balanced and overall a smooth experience :)

Not too sure if the above is something you have planned for in your design but just putting it here for a second look that your application will certainly benefit.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Faisal.